# retrieve dynamically created values of hidden input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

The following is the form created via php.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/resources/11" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<label for="tag">Tagname</label>
<input class="form-control" id="tags" name="tagname" type="text">
</div>
<div id="tagnames" class="control-group clearfix">
    <div class="tag-wrapper pull-left">
        <button data-original-title='This is about quantum description.' data- placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default tag_tooltip" type="button">
            <span class="tagname">
                quantum <i class='fa fa-times cancel'></i>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tag-wrapper pull-left">
        <button data-original-title='This is about kids!' data-placement="top" data- toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default tag_tooltip" type="button">
            <span class="tagname">
                kids <i class='fa fa-times cancel'></i>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <input id="tag_ids" name="tag_ids" type="hidden" value="4,5">
</div>
<div id="tagname"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit_button">
    <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
    Update
</button>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="http://localhost:8000/resources">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

[image]

**I want to `alert(4) or alert(5)` whichever corresponding tagname I click on.And I should be able to remove that id from the value.** 
Can anyone please help me? 
I been scratching for two days for this problem.

Comment: how fa-times related to 4 or 5?

Comment: `$('span .tagname').val();` this line suggest to find `.tagname` in the available `span` on the page. This is where your issue seems to be, one suggestion is this as ids are unique per element can't you just do `$('#tag_ids').val();`

Comment: Please, see the updated question. .fa-times is for 'cancel' icon class. When I click on that icon, I should be able to delete that value from input hidden field value.So that I can send those remaining values after deletion back to the database.

Comment: fa fa-times cancel doesnt have any value in it.

Comment: @Jai: I had tried the way you suggested. It alerts both the values whichever tag I click on. I want only the value of the tag that I click on.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: So, what would be the suggestion from you side, plz ?

Comment: @shankar posted an answer you can take a look at that, if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest  you to do this way by splitting into arrays and get the index:

```
$('.tag_tooltip .fa-times').on('click', function(){
      var o     = $('#tag_ids').val().split(','), // creates an array
          idx   = $(this).closest('.tag-wrapper').index(), // get the index of closest parent
          value = o.splice(idx, 1); // remove the value

      $('#tag_ids').val(value); // apply the new values
      alert($('#tag_ids').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jai. Yes, it worked the way I was looking for! Thank you for your time.